# Зачем до сих пор присутствуют настройки ширины и высоты в «custom-header» и настройки ширины в «content_width»?

Tags: wordpress, themes

Зачем до сих пор присутствуют настройки ширины и высоты в `custom-header` и настройки ширины в `content_width`?

В чём их предназначение, если они только мешают и, по большому счёту, ничего не решают?

Или я чего-то не понимаю? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться именно в сути вопроса.

Comment: О чем речь? Какая тема, в каком месте? Приведите пример кода.

Comment: @KAGG Design, речь не о теме или куске кода, я хочу понять в принципе, зачем это надо в настоящее время, ведь всё можно сделать и без этих параметров.

Comment: Как обычно. Я задал 3 вопроса, ответ на 1. Вы что, считаете, что в WP вот эти настройки, что вы привели, во вех темах? Так вы глубоко заблуждаетесь. Покажите, где это у вас.